# Opening pdf with other app from assets folder, workarounds

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent, android-external-storage

In my app, I've got some pdf's stored in my assets folder. I've seen libraries for opening pdf-pages, but I think that apps such as quickoffice are better at showing the pdf's than the libraries I've seen. Therefore, i wish to show the pdf using `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf");
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

However, this is not possible because third party apps are not allowed to acces files in my package. Therefore I need to copy the files to the external storage and provide that file to the intent.

That brings my to my question: my pdf's are quite big in size, so I think it'd be stupid to store them twice (once in my assets folder and once on the external storage). So I'm wondering if there is a work-around for this. Could i for example do:

```
//Copy file to external storage
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf");
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
//Delete file from external storage
```

Is this a good work-around or will this cause problems with the pdf-viewing app? Or is there a different work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Therefore I need to copy the files to the external storage and provide that file to the intent.

You can also try [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), a canned `ContentProvider`, based on Google's `FileProvider`, that streams from assets.

For multiple assets, this should work for the `StreamProvider` XML metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <asset
        name="whatevs"/>

</paths>
```

That should resolve all `content://your.authority.name.goes.here/whatevs/*` `Uri` values (for various values of `*`) to files inside of `assets/`. If you want to limit the scope to some specific subdirectory of `assets/` (say, `assets/goodstuff/`), you would use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <asset
        name="whatevs"
        path="goodstuff/"/>

</paths>
```

And, if this does not work, it should, so feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/issues) with a reproducible test case.

> Is this a good work-around or will this cause problems with the pdf-viewing app?

`startActivity()` is asynchronous, and so the external PDF viewer will never be able to access the file this way.

Comment: Thanks! Excactly what I need! However, the demo uses just 1 pdf, how does it work with multiple pdf's?

Comment: @Merlin: See updated answer, as it was easier to do that than shoehorn it all into a comment... :-)

Comment: Okay, but do I have to add every pdf to the paths.xml or do I only have to add the directory which all pdf's are in?

Comment: So say I want to refer to 1.pdf, which is inside the `goodstuff` folder. Can I use `content://your.authority.name.goes.here/whatevs/1.pdf` as a URI whithout having added 1.pdf in the paths.xml? Is that correct?

Comment: @Merlin: Using the second example XML metadata, that should work (with an appropriate substitution for `your.authority.name.goes.here`, of course). Again, if it doesn't, that's a bug.

Comment: Awesome! Going to check this out! Thank you so much!