# How to share txt/htm file from assets golder in android

Tags: android, share, assets

i am developing a program that shows some html gile placed in assets folder. also i put a button and i want when users touch it the showing html file share from bluetooth/attached email/... how can i share my files in assets folder?
please help me and i'm sorry for my bad english speaking. thank you.
its my code but it dosnt work

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
shareIntent.setType("text/html");        
Uri theUri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/asphalt3.htm");          
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,theUri);        
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, ""));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening pdf with other app from assets folder, workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063259/opening-pdf-with-other-app-from-assets-folder-workarounds)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using getAssets() method?

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("asphalt3.htm");
```

Comment: Post your stack trace please.